# RabbitListener using same thread over and over in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp

I want to test how a RabbitListener behaves when multiple requests are sent to it, kind of load testing. So here's what I have done - I created a rabbit listener:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "one.two.three.queue")
public void queueConsumer1(Message message) throws JsonProcessingException, InterruptedException {
    Country country = objectMapper.readValue(new String(message.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), Country.class);

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" - "+country.getName());

    Thread.sleep(10000); //  assuming the whole process after this takes 10 seconds
}
```

This listener is inside a spring boot application. In spring boot, default thread pool size is 200. Before starting this application, I have queued 20 messages of type country in RabbitMQ server.

When I started the application, I was hoping it would print country names with different thread names all at once. But it is printing country names with same thread name and it takes ten second gap between each country.

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-1 - DRC
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-1 - South Africa
```

I am not able to understand this behavior, As so many threads (up to 200) are available in thread pool, it should use them instead of using the same thread.

Comment: You are confusing things. The threadpool of 200 threads is for handling http requests and is the threadpool from Tomcat (the default container) it is not usable for Spring Boot. To use multiple concurrent handlers for rabbit-mq you need to configure it as such (as explained in the manual).

Comment: @M.Deinum So if there are 1001 request packets targeted for a queue, and each packet takes 10 seconds to process, then the last packet will have to wait for 10000 seconds?

Comment: Read... No you don't *but** the thread pool used for HTTP request handling has **nothing** to do with the threads used by RabbitMQ. As I mentioned if you want to have concurrent consumers then configure the listener as such, it will use a separate thread pool .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "concurrency" parameter to @RabbitListener:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/annotation/RabbitListener.html#concurrency()